# Force field initialize not by constructor in c++

Tags: design-patterns, c++

My parent class has a vector field

I want to force child classes to push in that vector as many as items they have. At least one item

example:

```
class Options {
    protected:
        vector<string> optionItems;
    public:
        void printItemsInConsole(){
            // prints items on console
        }
}

class MainOptions : public Options {
    //have to pushback {Open game, Open highScores, Exit} options for example

}

class SideOptions : public Options {
    // have to pushback {Clear game database, Uninstall game, Back to main menu} options for example
}
```

How to force child classes to push back their items?

I don't want to pass items in constructor and then put them in vector just right there, because some times items would be a lot, so it's not a clean way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no way to force a subclass or user of a class to perform certain actions after the constructor has completed. So any initialization work MUST be done in the constructor. There is rarely a good reason to ever have a half-initialized object.

Here, the typical way would be to have the base class take a collection as constructor parameter, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Options {
protected:
    std::vector<std::string> items;
public:
    Options(std::vector<std::string>&& items) : items{std::move(items)} {}

    void printItemsInConsole(){
        for (auto& item : items)
          std::cout << item << '\n';
    }
};

class MainOptions : public Options {
public:
    MainOptions() : Options({"Open game", "Open Highscores", "Exit"}) {}

};

class SideOptions : public Options {
public:
     SideOptions() : Options({"Clear game data", "Uninstall", "Back to main menu"}) {}
};

int main() {
  MainOptions o;
  o.printItemsInConsole();
}
```

Note that the use of C++11 list initialization is a terse way for the subclass to provide these items. If you do not want to provide these items inline, you can always use a helper function to construct the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is not the most effective way to ensure that the base class object gets the data it needs. If you want to ensure that `Options` built for a purpose has certain data, then you should have its constructor be *given* that data. And then you provide certain functions that create different types of options:

```
class Options {
    private:
        vector<string> optionItems;

    public:

        Options(vector<string> &&opts) : optionItems(std::move(opts))
        {
            assert(!optionItems.empty());
        }

        void printItemsInConsole(){
            // prints items on console
        }
}

Options MainOptions()
{
    vector<string> opts;
    //have to pushback {Open game, Open highScores, Exit} options for example
    return Options(std::move(opts));
}

Options SideOptions()
{
    vector<string> opts;
    // have to pushback {Clear game database, Uninstall game, Back to main menu} options for example
    return Options(std::move(opts));
}
```